# AngularJS Spring CRUD delete 405 Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm making simple CRUD application with AngularJS and Spring.
When i make DELETE call, it send this error:

```
Request method 'DELETE' not supported
```

Angular function

```
$scope.delete = function(item){
    $http({
        method:"DELETE",
        url:"/task/"+item.id,            
    }).then(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++){
            if(item.id==$scope.tasks[i].id){
                $scope.tasks.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Spring delete controller

```
`@DeleteMapping("/task/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public  HttpStatus delete(@PathVariable String id){
        System.out.println("Call 1");
        taskService.delete(id);
        System.out.println("Call 2");
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }`
```

Comment: change `@DeleteMapping("/task/{id]")` to `@DeleteMapping("/task/{id}")`

Comment: oh, it's a typo

Comment: Please enable debug logging for Spring and show us if your `delete` handler method is registered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add path variable name like `@PathVariable('id') String id`